# How to achieved multiple nested screens

Tags: react-native, react-navigation-stack

Having trouble with my StackNavigator with two another screens in the nested, below are the nested stack I want to achieve.

```
Items
-Help (already achieve this nested)
    -Help Details
-Topup
    -Topup Details
-Services (I want to achieve something like this);
    -Service name (Babysitting)
        -service name details (Babysitting details)
```

This is ony my `DashboardNavigator`

```
function DashboardNavigator() {
    return (
        <StackDashboard.Navigator initialRouteName="Dashboard">
            <StackDashboard.Screen name="Topup" component={TopupStack} options={navOptionHandler} />
            <StackDashboard.Screen name="Services" component={ServicesStack} options={navOptionHandler} />
            <StackDashboard.Screen name="BabySitting" component={BabySittingStack} options={navOptionHandler} />
        </StackDashboard.Navigator>
    )
}

function BabySittingStack() {
    <StackBabySitting.Navigator initialRouteName="BabySitting">
        <StackBabySitting.Screen name="BabySitting" component={BabySitting} options={navOptionHandler} />
        <StackBabySitting.Screen name="BabySittingDetails" component={BabySittingDetails} options={navOptionHandler} />
    </StackBabySitting.Navigator>
}

function ServicesStack() {
    return (
        <StackServices.Navigator initialRouteName="Services">
            <StackServices.Screen name="Services" component={Services} options={navOptionHandler} />
            <StackServices.Screen name="BabySitting" component={BabySittingStack} options={navOptionHandler} />
        </StackServices.Navigator>
    )
}
```

This will be my `screen` that will go to my `details screen`

```
<SafeAreaView>
            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.item} onPress={() => navigation.navigate('BabySittingDetails')}>
                <Text style={styles.title}>BabySitting</Text>
                <Image
                    style={styles.imageItem}
                    source={IMAGE.ICON_NEXT} resizeMode="contain" />
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </SafeAreaView>
```

Comment: What's your problem ? Please give us more details and your code (a minimal repro) so we can help.

Comment: @QuentinGrisel one moment I will add my code here.

Comment: @QuentinGrisel babysitting is `service name` with `service name details` on it. The `help` and `topup` are the same I just added a sample stack there. Everytime I used that kind of nested my `onPress={() => navigation.navigate('BabySittingDetails')}` gives me an error of `undefined navigation` even though it's already declared.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is your problem but `BabySittingDetails` is accessible in `BabySittingStack`. `BabySittingStack` and `ServicesStack` are at the same level, so you can't access babySittingdetails like that. You can test to move your `BabySittingComponent` inside your `ServicesStack`.

But I don't think you should get this kind of error with your current navigation architecture. If it does not solve your problem then please show us your `BabySittingDetails` component entirely and eventually reproduce your problem on a snack expo. You can use [this boilerplate](https://snack.expo.io/@satya164/react-navigation-5-boilerplate) to reproduce your problem (ios is working fine as well as web, android have some trouble with stylesheet i don't know why).